# Error response from daemon: failed to parse Dockerfile: Syntax error - can't find = in "RUN". Must be of the form: name=value

Tags: docker, sonarqube

When I'm trying to build the Dockerfile from aws codebuild I'm getting the this error as
**"Error response from daemon: failed to parse Dockerfile: Syntax error - can't find = in "RUN". Must be of the form: name=value"**
In code build I'm using ubuntu as environmment with aws/codebuild/standard 5.0 runtime version.
Here is my Dockerfile and buildspec.yml:

```
FROM alipine:3.12
ARG SONARQUBE_VERSION=8.9.0.43852
COPY ./sonarqube-8.9.0.43852.zip   /opt/'sonarqube-${SONARQUBE_VERSION}.zip'
RUN chmod 777 /opt/sonarqube-8.9.0.43852.zip
---------------
--------------

COPY --chown=sonarqube:sonarqube run.sh sonar.sh ${SONARQUBE_HOME}/bin/
USER sonarqube
RUN chmod 777 ${SONARQUBE_HOME}/bin/run.sh; \
RUN chmod 777 ${SONARQUBE_HOME}/bin/sonar.sh
VOLUME $SONARQUBE_HOME
WORKDIR ${SONARQUBE_HOME}
EXPOSE 9000
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/sonarqube/bin/run.sh"]
CMD ["/opt/sonarqube/bin/sonar.sh"]
```

**And the below is my buildspec.yml**

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR.....
      - aws --version
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <MyAccountId>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sonarqube
      
  build:
    commands:
      - aws s3 cp s3://ravitej/SonarQube/sonarqube-8.9.0.43852.zip  .
      - chmod +x sonarqube-8.9.0.43852.zip
      - echo $(pwd)
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - echo $(docker version)
      - REPOSITORY_URI=<MyAccountID>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sonarqube
      - IMAGE_TAG=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG .
      
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"sonarqube","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
      - echo imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
    files: imagedefinitions.json
```

Banging my head againt the table for the past 2 days.

Please help..
This is the error from code build:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmp9h.png)

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?

Comment: @BMitch 
To be simple I'm getting the error "Error response from daemon: failed to parse Dockerfile: Syntax error - can't find = in "RUN". Must be of the form: name=value" while building the dockerfile from codebuild. plz find the screenshot above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By minimal I'm thinking of a  Dockerfile with a `FROM` and single 1-2 line `RUN` step. Preferably based on a small image like `busybox` to make it easier for anyone that wants to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @BMitch I have cut short the Dockerfile for easy understanding. Please check. This is my very first post on stackoverflow. Please bare with me. If you want me to cut it short further , plz let me know.. Thanks.

Comment: @BMitch The issue is sorted.. There is a syntax mismatch between ENV declaration and RUN command.Both ENV and the RUN command are not properly aligned/indented ..which lead to this error.Thanks for support

Answer (score 22):

I just had a similar problem which lead me here and the issue was a trailing \ in my Dockerfile. In your case I guess it is this line:

```
RUN chmod 777 ${SONARQUBE_HOME}/bin/run.sh; \
```

Which causes problems for the next line.

Answer (score 1):

This also happens when you try to add a comment using hash at the end of the line, e.g. like `# OK` here:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
[..]
ENV RSTUDIO_VER=1.3.1073 # OK
[..]
```

The `docker build`'s parser won't like it!

```
$ docker build -t mirekphd/ml-cpu-r40-rs-cust .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  142.2MB

Error response from daemon: failed to parse Dockerfile: Syntax error - can't find = in "#". Must be of the form: name=value
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was related to a comment in the Dockerfile. As mirekphd mentioned, this wont work.

```
ENV MAX_JOBS=8 # offending comment
RUN some more stuff
```

Removing the `# offending comment` from the ENV line solved it for me.